# Named arguments are not allowed for non-Kotlin functions - Network Mapper

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm creating a network mapper.  My data class is in Java and when I try to map the data I'm getting the error `Named arguments are not allowed for non-Kotlin functions`.

Part of the difficulty is that my Movie data class extends a Results class.  I can't figure out if I should be mapping out Movie or Results.  When I map out Movie I get the same error, but also that no value has been passed for result.

I'm not totally sure how to map this. Does it need to be converted?

Network Mapper:

```
class MovieNetworkMapper : EntityMapper<MovieNetworkEntity, Result> {

override fun mapFromEntity(entity: MovieNetworkEntity): Result {
    return Result(
        id = entity.id,
        title = entity.title,
        overview = entity.overview,
        poster_path = entity.posterPath,
        release_date = entity.releaseDate,
        vote_average = entity.voteAverage
    )
}

override fun mapToEntity(domainModel: Result): MovieNetworkEntity {
    return MovieNetworkEntity(
        id = domainModel.id,
        title = domainModel.title,
        overview = domainModel.overview,
        posterPath = domainModel.poster_path,
        releaseDate = domainModel.release_date,
        voteAverage = domainModel.vote_average
    )
    }
}
```

Movie data class (Java):

```
public class Movie {

    @NotNull
    public final List<? extends Result> results;

    public Movie(List<? extends Result> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}
```

Result data class (Java):

```
public class Result {
    public int id;
    public String overview;
    public String poster_path;
    public String release_date;
    public String title;
    public double vote_average;

    public Result(
            int id,
            String overview,
            String poster_path,
            String release_date,
            String title,
            Double vote_average) {
        this.id = id;
        this.overview = overview;
        this.poster_path = poster_path;
        this.release_date = release_date;
        this.title = title;
        this.vote_average = vote_average;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message seem pretty clear: `Result` is in Java, thus you can't call the Result constructor with named parameters. Is there a reason Result is written in Java?

Comment: I'm refactoring an existing project, but also, as part of the requirements I must have files written in Java (this is an assignment for a potential job).  This is one of those files.

Comment: Taking a look at `Result` class it seems a) its not a record class or override hashcode/equals and b) It is not immutable.  It seems a weird choice of convension, usually you'd have a `Result<T>` monad success/error which contains a payload which I'd have thought would be a `List<Movie>` - or a `Error` respectively. Currently `Result` is a movie, not that you'd know that by its generic name.

Answer (score 3):

Either

1)Rewrite Results to be in Kotlin (if you can)

2)Don't use named parameters, use ordered ones.  You'd just need to move title to before voterAverage and remove all the names= parts of those lines.